# Unwanted irregular layout when using \multirow

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, booktabs, layout

I am an experienced user of latex but new to constructing tables. My problem is illustrated with this example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering  
    \caption{ }\label{tablea1.1b} 
        \begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}{l l c}
        \toprule
            Moon& Earth&  1.0  \\
        \midrule 
            Jupiter& Sun& 5.5 \\   
        \midrule      
            \multirow{2}{*}{Saturn} & {Sun}& 6.7\\
            {} & {}& {4.2}  \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

When I run this I get the following:
[image: Table with wrong format]

I want to show one number for each of the first two lines but two numbers corresponding to "Saturn" and "Sun" in the last line. But those two words are misaligned in my table. Ideally "Sun" should be on the same level as "Saturn", that is in line with the horizontal gap between the two numbers in column 3.

How can I achieve that layout, please?

(I am aware that horizontal lines in tables are regarded as ugly. I have used them here to show which numbers in column three go with which pairs of planets.)

Comment: Place "sun" in a multirow comand, as well. \multirow{2}{*}{Saturn} & \multirow{2}{*}{Sun}  should result in the desired output.

Comment: @leandriis Thanks. I get this error message:Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.21 ^^I\end{tabularx}
If I then press <return> in the console, getting more error messages, the table eventually is produced in the correct format. So I am more than halfway to a solution. Can you help ?

Comment: Sorry for the typo in my previous comment the second argument of multirow should not be empty but still contain the asterisk.

Comment: Apart from that, using tabularx for such a table, especially when used without any X type column, does not really make sense. A regular tabular should work perfectly fine here.

Comment: It is not my real table, just a simplified example. With the asterisk everything now works perfectly. If you put your comment as an Answer I could formally accept it.

Comment: Sure, I'll do so in a minute. I'll also include an alternative suggestion using nested tabulars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, "Sun"  should also be inside of a `\multirow` command in order to vertically center it with respect to the two table rows. In the following example, I also included two alternative approaches based on nested tabulars or on the `\Block` command from the `nicematrix` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering  
    \caption{With multirow}\label{tablea1.1b} 
        \begin{tabular}{l l c}
        \toprule
            Moon& Earth&  1.0  \\
        \midrule 
            Jupiter& Sun& 5.5 \\   
        \midrule      
            \multirow{2}{*}{Saturn} & \multirow{2}{*}{Sun}& 6.7\\
             & & 4.2  \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 


 \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering  
    \caption{With nested tabulars}\label{tablea1.1b} 
        \begin{tabular}{l l c}
        \toprule
            Moon & Earth&  1.0  \\
        \midrule 
            Jupiter & Sun& 5.5 \\   
        \midrule      
            Saturn & Sun & \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} 6.7 \\ 4.2\end{tabular}  \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 


 \begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering  
    \caption{With nicematrix}\label{tablea1.1b} 
        \begin{NiceTabular}{l l c}
        \toprule
            Moon& Earth&  1.0  \\
        \midrule 
            Jupiter& Sun& 5.5 \\   
        \midrule      
            \Block{2-1}{Saturn} & \Block{2-1}{Sun}& 6.7\\
             & & 4.2  \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering  
        \caption{ }\label{tablea1.1b} 
        \begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}{l l c}
            \toprule
            Moon& Earth&  1.0  \\
            \midrule 
            Jupiter& Sun& 5.5 \\   
            \midrule      
            \multirow{2}{*}{Saturn} &\multirow{2}{*}{Sun}& 6.7\\
            {} & {}& {4.2}  \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

By use of the `makcell` package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}   % <---
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{}
\label{tablea1.1b}
\begin{tabularx}{0.3\textwidth}{X X c}
    \toprule
Moon    & Earth &  1.0  \\
    \midrule
Jupiter & Sun   & 5.5   \\
    \midrule
Saturn  & Sun   & \makecell{6.7\\4.2}  \\   % <---
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]